# How can I reference the objects created in v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

Just doing a litle experiment while learning VueJS. My question is how can I reference the marker object created using the v-for loop?

```
<gmap-marker
      :key="index"
      v-for="(m, index) in markers"
      :icon="m.icon"
      :position="m.position"
      :clickable="true"
      :draggable="true"
      @click="center=m.position"
    ></gmap-marker>
```

Im planning to attach an ID to each of the markers created then collect them in an object literal with the ID as the key and the marker object as the value. This is so that I can reference each marker using their id.

Is it the proper way to do it in VueJs?

Thanks!

Comment: Keep the logic out of the template whenever possible. Transform the data before using it in a template.

Comment: Can you give an example on how I can further improve the above code when I take the logic out of the template?

Comment: I just meant to use computed or methods on the component to prepare the data to be used, unless I misinterpreted _"markers created"_. Note that it's not me who downvoted, I was just sharing good practices ;)

Comment: Its alright i dont worry about downvotes. :) Im just beginning to wrap my head on this VueJs thing thats why i asked if there are any proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ref`s:

```
  <gmap-marker
      :key="index"
      v-for="(m, index) in markers"
      :icon="m.icon"
      :position="m.position"
      :clickable="true"
      :draggable="true"
      @click="center=m.position"
      ref="marker"
    ></gmap-marker> <!-- notice the addition of ref="marker" attribute -->
```

And later reference using:

```
this.$refs.marker[index]
```

Where `index` is an integer. The `[index]` is necessary because you are using `ref` in a `v-for`.

Quick demo:

```js
Vue.component('gmap-marker', {
  props: ['icon'],
  template: '<div>marker {{ icon }}</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    markers: [{
      icon: 'aaa'
    }, {
      icon: 'bbb'
    }, {
      icon: 'ccc'
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    printMarkers() {
      console.log(this.$refs.marker.length);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <gmap-marker
      :key="index"
      v-for="(m, index) in markers"
      :icon="m.icon"
      :position="m.position"
      :clickable="true"
      :draggable="true"
      @click="center=m.position"
      ref="marker"
  ></gmap-marker>
  <hr>
  <button @click="printMarkers">Print Marker Refs at Console</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a custom ID instead of the index?

Comment: Yes, just do `:id="'foo-bar-' + index"`, for example. (`index` is not necessary, but you do should generate unique `id`s.) Another possibility: `:id="m.id"`, considering such `id` property exist at `markers: [{id: 123, ...}]`.

Comment: Yes that's what im looking for. Thank you for your help!